# New power supply and now HDDs are not recognized

Tags: hard-drive, boot, bios, power-supply

So I upgraded to a new X4 ULTRA power supply that was recommended to me by a local TigerDirect store.  After installing it along with a new liquid cooling system, I booted it up and it automatically fried my CD Drive.  After that I noticed that the OS wouldn't start and figured out that none of the 4 HDDs in my computer were being recognized by the BIOS.  I feel them spool at a steady pace and have tried new cables and connections but to no avail.  I triple checked all of the connections and cables and have no idea what is wrong.  This isn't the first time I changed a PS or CPU cooling system but I am at a dead end.  Any ideas, aside from buying a USB HDD reader and seeing if they are all fried?

Also, this is a stock Gateway mobo with the mobo USB connections already dead.  Could the new PS have fried the SATA connections??

Answer (score 1):

You have specified X4 ULTRA power supply. But you haven't mentioned its wattage. It is always better to go through the manual before you physically connect and experiment. I guess the power supply you connected was not compatible with your board and peripherals.

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely. It could have easily have taken out the PCB. You can find replacement PCBs online but most of the time they're a crap shoot, it just depends on the drive.

Comment: All 4 of the HDDs are toasted. Wtf.........I luckily back up in intervals. I will have a serious talk with the company soon.

Answer (score 0):

I had a problem once with a brand new power supply that was not working as expected and it turned out it was because the input voltage switch (to select between 120v and 240v) at the back of the unit was not in the right position. Make sure the switch is at the right voltage which is 120v for North America and 240v for, I guess, most other locations.